# Why is pip not listed in easy_install on CentOS 6? Where to get it?

Tags: python, easy-install, centos-6, pip

I am trying to install pip for python on CentOS 6. I thought of installing it through easy_install but it is not there. I tried to find easy_install with find command, but no luck. 
I tried to re-install python with yum and still not able to find easy_install.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In some distribution easy_install not come with the default python.

So, you to download it and install.

```
#wget http://peak.telecommunity.com/dist/ez_setup.py
#python ez_setup.py
```

After installing the ez_setup.py, you can find the easy_install, using that you can install pip module as follow.

```
#easy_install pip
```

Answer (score 9):

Both setuptools (`python-setuptools`) and pip (`python-pip`) are in [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL).

Comment: `python-pip` is what I was looking for. Thanks!